# Formatting vertical labels (vaxis) with masking money in the chart google?

Tags: api, graph, charts, google-visualization

In the end of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfQpLvl6tpw, the chart has the vertical labels formated with money mask. Using the following code:

```
var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
                {prefix: 'R$ ', negativeParens: true, negativeColor: 'red'}
            );
            formatter.format(data, 1);
            formatter.format(data, 2);
```

I get the same result to the mouseover points labels, but not to fixed vertical labels on left side like the video.

What can I do to get this result?

Comment: Obs: I want to do that using javascript not google docs. The video was just a example.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  option:

```
vAxis:{format:'R$ #,###'}
```

---

Demo:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', 'R$/kg'],
    ['Silver', 5477.44],
    ['Gold', 36121.36],
    ['Platinum', 32407.95], // CSS-style declaration
  ]);

  var options = {
    vAxis: {
      format: 'R$ #,###'
    }
  };
  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    prefix: 'R$ '
  });
  formatter.format(data, 1);

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```